# Resizing WordPress Jetpack Tiled Gallery with JS

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jetpack

On my WordPress theme I have a hidden `div` with a Jetpack gallery inside of it. I have a button that when clicked makes the `div` appear using jquery's `.slideDown()`. The jetpack gallery inside the `div` is only showing at 100px wide and will not fill the space within the `div`. However, when I resize the window the gallery immediately fills the space in the `div` like it is suppose to.

I set the `div` to `display: block;` and it shows properly, but when the `div` is set to `display:none;` and is then shown using jquery's `.slideDown()` it is only 100px wide.

Is there a js function I can call on my button's `.click()` event that can trigger the Jetpack Gallery to resize to the `div`? It seems to resize when the windows resizes so I figure there must be a way to make it resize when the `.slideDown()` is completed.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
[gallery]
</div>

<button id="btn">Show</button>
```

CSS

```
#container { 
  display:none; 
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

JS

```
    $('#btn').click(function(e) {
        $('#container').slideDown();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
    $('#container').slideDown();
    $('.tiled-gallery').resize();
});
```

`.tiled-gallery` is the div created by jetpack that wraps the gallery